# Firebase analytics (6.3.0) Note: uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, firebase-analytics

I'm receiving the following error while using Firebase analytics (6.3.0):

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-6.3.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseanalytics\FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to version firebase analytics 6.2 to resolve the issue temporarily.

```
firebase_analytics: ^6.2.0
```

Comment: It didn't help for me :\

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your analytics version:smile:

firebase_analytics: ^9.3.4