# Is there any way to handle push notifications with flutter on android devices?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to manage a push notification system with flutter on my Android device and I can't. I tried some tutorials but never got a result.

I recently tried a tutorial and I have this in my Run window:

Note: /home/uriel/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-5.0.0+4/android/src/main/java/com/dexterous/flutterlocalnotifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Is there a way to manage this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65333984/firebase-analytics-6-3-0-note-uses-or-overrides-a-deprecated-api

Comment: From what I see, it's only a warning, no error? If there is an actual error can you provide us the exact error?

Comment: There are no errors, the problem is that the code does not even run!